# Create an <img> tag and fadeOut it with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, fadeout, jquery-after

I would like make the `img` fadeOut after 2 seconds. Right now I am fading out my `input`. What I am doing wrong in that code below?

```
$(ctrl)
 .closest("tr")
 .find("td:nth-child(2) input")
 .addClass("input-test")
 .after('<img id="input_img" src="http://i.imgur.com/2LGbUV2.png" />')
 .fadeOut(2000);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The issue is because `after()` returns the original element in the selector (in your case `td:nth-child(2) input`), not the element which was created.

To fix this you need to append the `img` so that you still have a reference to it in the JS code and can then call `fadeOut()` on it. Try this:

```
var $input = $(ctrl).closest("tr").find("td:nth-child(2) input").addClass("input-test");
$('<img id="input_img" src="http://i.imgur.com/2LGbUV2.png" />').insertAfter($input).fadeOut(2000);
```

Alternatively you can append as you currently are, and select the new DOM content separately:

```
$(ctrl).closest("tr").find("td:nth-child(2) input").addClass("input-test").after('<img id="input_img" src="http://i.imgur.com/2LGbUV2.png" />');
$('#input_img').fadeOut(2000);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
$(ctrl).closest("tr").find("td:nth-child(2) input").addClass("input-test").after( '<img id="input_img" src="http://i.imgur.com/2LGbUV2.png" />' );
$(document).find("#input_img").fadeOut(2000)
```

Comment: `$(document).find('#id')` seems a little wasteful when you can just use `$('#id')`

Comment: I am not sure, if it will find this dynamically generated `img` tag